# Sincronizar datos entre dos base de datos con la misma estructura

Tags: sql, postgresql

Necesito pasar los datos de una base de datos a otra con la misma estructura, el problema es que ambas base de datos están en uso, en ambas se pueden insertar registros diferentes y están en lugares diferentes.

Por ej.: en la DB1 ingresamos una factura del cliente1, en la DB2 se ingresa la factura del cliente2 y necesitamos que en la DB2 este la factura del cliente1 y cliente2.

El problema que tenemos se da por los ID, que al insertar sin el ID los datos de la cabecera de la factura (tabla: facturas_venta) para que no muestre error de ID duplicado luego no podemos insertar el detalle (tabla: facturas_venta_detalle) porque no tenemos el ID y tenemos que modificar la consulta a mano.

Estoy buscando una manera más práctica de pasar los datos que tener que armar un ETL por cada tabla que inserte sin el ID, y luego en cada tabla relacionada resuelver el nuevo ID para poder insertar los datos.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo fácil sin tener que crear un ETL por cada tabla de esta manera, con alguna herramientas u otra forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Las herramientas para hacer esto se llaman ETLs. Pedir hacer un ETL sin usar un ETL no tiene mucho sentido.

Comment: Es cierto, pero estoy buscando una manera más práctica de pasar los datos que tener que armar un ETL por cada tabla que inserte sin el ID, y luego en cada tabla relacionada resuelva el nuevo ID para poder insertar, modifico la consulta para aclarar lo que estoy buscando. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra manera es no usar un ID autonumérico para estos casos. Las bases de datos permiten poner claves basadas en registros de texto y/o tener claves compuestas. De hecho usar ID numérico cuando ya existe un campo que determina funcionalmente es innecesario.

De hecho las facturas ya tienen que tener un número distinto al momento de imprimirlas (esto puede lograrse prefijando un número de "punto de venta" o "Número de talonario" O "id de sucursal").

Entonces se puede tener como clave primaria compuesta (sucursal, número).

Si estás usando un framework que sí o sí necesita que sea un solo campo y que sea numérico, se puede preasingar números pares para una base e impares para la otra (o algo similar).

Comment: lo de usar numeros pares e impares para las DB lo puedo realizar modificando las secuencias del campo serial y luego puedo pasar los cambios con ETL, es una buena idea. voy a probar y te comento como resulta

Answer (score 0):

Una manera que tuve de arreglar un problema similar fue usando códigos UUID para las claves únicas. Generándolos aleatoriamente, es prácticamente imposible que se produzcan duplicados, incluso con particionados mucho mayores que 2.

Utilizando [UUID](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html) como tipo para el campo ID, sólo te hará falta algún mecanismo para asignar por defecto UUID aleatorios. El método que se recomienda es emplear la función `gen_random_uuid()` del módulo [pgcrypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html).

En mi caso, la alternativa que elegí fue usar el [módulo uuid](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/uuid.html) de python a través del [pl/pythonu](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython.html).

Comment: los UUID se puede generar automaticamente desde una funcion de postgres? para implementarlo tengo que migrar todos los datos a una DB nueva que utilice los UUID como clave primaria?

Comment: La función te la he puesto, `gen_random_uuid()` del paquete pgcrypto. Se asigna como valor por defecto del campo (de tipo UUID). Este campo hace de clave primaria hasta que la factura obtenga su número correcto al consolidar todas las facturas en un único servidor. Pero como dices que no puedes saber qué número tendrá la factura, estás obligado a usar el campo uuid para establecer todas las relaciones. Luego basta con añadir un campo para el número de factura que tendrá una relación 1-1 con el campo uuid.

Comment: Estoy viendo que `gen_random_uuid()` viene en postgres a partir de la versión 9.4. Para versiones anteriores se podría usar en su lugar `uuid_generate_v4()` del paquete `uuid-ossp` o la alternativa de usar plpythonu que he comentado.